# Accessing object functions by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I`m working on an interactive story using Jquery. My question is; I want to change the text everytime I click in a button to the next dialogue function, so I created an object with some functions that contains the dialogues. Since it's an object, not an array, how can I access it's elements by click count?

```
story ={ 
    dialogue: function(){
     $("p").text("My name is Richard");  
    },
     dialogue: function(){
     $('p').text("Nice to meet you!").hide().fadeIn(1000); 
    },
     dialogue: function(){
     $('p').text("what is your name").hide().fadeIn(1000); 
    }
};


var clickCount = 0;

var nextStatment = function() {
  $('p').text(story[clickCount]).hide().fadeIn(1000);
  clickCount++;

};

$('.slideBt1').on('click', nextStatment);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the next specification (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4) you can find that

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique. ... An object whose names
> are all unique is interoperable in the sense  that all software
> implementations receiving that object will agree on   the name-value
> mappings.

You should re-write your object, using unique keys or array.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an array to store the text and use that with indexes to set the next content

```js
story = ["My name is Richard", "Nice to meet you!", "what is your name"];

var clickCount = 0;
var nextStatment = function() {
  $('p').hide().text(story[clickCount] || '').fadeIn(1000);
  clickCount++;

};

$('.slideBt1').on('click', nextStatment);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click to start</p>
<button class="slideBt1">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try making story an `Array` of functions?

```
story = [ 
    function(){
     $("p").text("My name is Richard");  
    },
     function(){
     $('p').text("Nice to meet you!").hide().fadeIn(1000); 
    },
     function(){
     $('p').text("what is your name").hide().fadeIn(1000); 
    }
];


var clickCount = 0;

var nextStatment = function() {
  $('p').text(story[clickCount]).hide().fadeIn(1000);
  clickCount++;

};

$('.slideBt1').on('click', nextStatment);
```